# Thymeleaf inline javascript spring bean check for null with textual template modes

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I can't wrap my head around the syntax of the `Textual template modes` feature of Thymeleaf. Im trying to access a `bean` (works fine) and call a `getter` from where i get an another object from. This object can be null and i need to check it before i access the string i need.

How can i do this in one line by using the `[# th:if` expressions from Thymeleaf?

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
        //This does not work (i have tried multiple things)
        var string = /*[# th:if="${@bean.getObject()}"][[${@bean.getObject().getString()}]][/]*/ null;
</script>
```

Comment: A quick test (not exactly the same as your example) shows that I cannot combine the textual template syntax with the JavaScript [natural templating](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#javascript-natural-templates) feature where you enclose your expression inside a comment `var myString = /* ... */ null;`. If I remove the natural templating piece, my expression works as expected: `var myString = [# th:if="${foo} == 'bar'"][[${foo}]][/];`. Otherwise, it's interpreted as a comment. In case that helps.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question - I thought you explicitly wanted to use the [textual syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#textual-syntax) approach, instead of the more typical [JavaScript inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#javascript-inlining) approach. Otherwise, the answer from @metroids is the right approach, I think.

Comment: I tested my logic without the `/* ... */` and it worked. So you are correct. But if i remove those comment expressions, IntelliJ will complain and the .html file will not be rendered when opening it standalone in the browser. And i don't get why i have to remove them in that case..

Comment: "_why i have to remove them_" - you are combining two incompatible syntaxes. JavaScript inlining using comments means that Thymeleaf expects to find standard `${...}` expression syntax in `[[` and `]]` - whereas you were trying to use the textual `[#...][/]` syntax. You can find tutorials and examples in the links in my earlier comments for core Thymeleaf. For Spring, you can find SpEL documentation here: [Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions). SpEL is where you will find the "safe navigation" operator.

Comment: Reading the feature release of this, it should work as i tried it: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/395
If you scroll down to "Applying comments to any element" where they explain the combination of output expressions and comments in JAVASCRIPT. So im still confused why it did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to accomplish this, I would recommend the [safe navigation operator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-operator-safe-navigation) for this:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
  var string = /*[[${@bean.object?.string}]]*/ null;
</script>
```

You could also use a ternary expression:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
  var string = /*[[${@bean.object != null ? @bean.object.string : null}]]*/ null;
</script>
```

Comment: This works, thanks. But how would a more complex logic look like? If i for example additionally need to check if the string is null or not? What are the limits of this syntax? I can't find any good tutorial or examples online..

Comment: IMO, if you want to get more complicated, you should just serialize the entire object `var bean = /*[[${@bean}]]*/ null;` and deal with nulls in the JavaScript.